# Is access to ruby Array thread-safe?

Tags: arrays, ruby, multithreading, thread-safety

Say that I have N threads accessing an array with N elements. The array has been prepared before the threads start. Each thread will access a different element (the thread I will access element I, both for reading and writing).

In theory, I'd expect such an access pattern not to cause any race conditions, but will Ruby actually guarantee thread safety in this case?

Comment: If each thread is accessing different element of array and if these objects do not share references to the same mutable objects, then you have no shared-resource issue and thread-safety is not a concern. However, this is quite tricky to enforce, so extra care is required - as soon as your array start mutating, you'll have a problem.

Comment: Instead of array and index, just pass the element to the thread. This ensures that you're not re-assigning the element accidentally. (or modify the array in other ways)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but will Ruby actually guarantee thread safety in this case

Ruby does not have a defined memory model, so there are no guarantees of any kind.

YARV has a *Giant VM Lock* which prevents multiple Ruby threads from running at the same time, which gives some *implicit* guarantees, but this is a private, internal implementation detail of YARV. For example, TruffleRuby, JRuby, and Rubinius *can* run multiple Ruby threads in parallel.

Since there is no specification of what the behavior should be, any Ruby implementation is free to do whatever they want. Most commonly, Ruby implementors try to mimic the behavior of YARV, but even that is not well-defined. In YARV, data structures are generally not thread-safe, so if you want to mimic the behavior of YARV, do you make all your data structures not thread-safe? But in YARV, also multiple threads cannot run at the same time, so in a lot of cases, operations are *implicitly* thread-safe, so if you want to mimic YARV, should you make your data structures thread-safe?

Or, in order to mimic YARV, should you prevent multiple threads from running at the same time? But, being able to run multiple threads in parallel is actually one of the reasons why people choose, for example JRuby over YARV.

As you can see, this is very much not a trivial question.

The best solution is to verify the behavior of each Ruby implementation separately. Actually, that is the *second best* solution.

The best solution is to use something like the [concurrent-ruby Gem](http://www.concurrent-ruby.com/) where *someone else* has already done the work of verifying the behavior of each Ruby implementation for you. The concurrent-ruby maintainers have a close relationship with several Ruby implementations (Chris Seaton, one of the two lead maintainers of concurrent-ruby is also the lead developer of TruffleRuby, a JRuby core developer, and a member of ruby-core, for example), and so you can generally be certain that everything that is in concurrent-ruby is safe on all supported Ruby implementations (currently YARV, JRuby, and TruffleRuby).

Concurrent Ruby has a `Concurrent::Array` class which is thread-safe. You can see how it is implemented here: https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby/blob/master/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/array.rb As you can see, for YARV, `Concurrent::Array` is actually the same as `::Array`, but for other implementations, more work is required.

The concurrent-ruby developers are also working on specifying Ruby's memory model, so that in the future, both programmers know what to expect and what not to expect, and implementors know what they are allowed to optimize and what they aren't.

Comment: Interesting perspective. Are there tools to experimentally verify the thread-safety of ruby programs? For C++ (and similar), we can use the [LLVM thread sanitizer ](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html), but I'm not aware of any similar tool for ruby.

Comment: I don't know of any such tool. Note: I added some information at the end which may be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

### Alternatives to Mutable Arrays

In standard Ruby implementations, an Array is *not* thread-safe. However, a [Queue](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Queue.html) is. On the other hand, a Queue is not quite an Array, so you don't have all the methods on Queue that you may be looking for.

The [Concurrent Ruby](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby) gem provides a thread-safe Array class, but as a rule thread-safe classes will be slower than those that aren't. Depending on your data this may not matter, but it's certainly a design consideration.

If you know from the beginning that you're going to be heavily reliant on threading, you should build your application on a Ruby implementation that offers concurrency and threading to begin with (e.g. consider JRuby or TruffleRuby), and design your application to take advantage of Ractors or use other concurrency models that treat data as immutable rather than sharing objects between threads.

Immutable data is a better pattern for threading than shared objects. You may or may not have problems with any given mutable object given enough due care, but [Ractors](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Ractor.html) and [fiber-local variables](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Thread.html#method-i-5B-5D) should be faster and safer than trying to make mutable objects threat-safe. YMMV, though.